# How to get Keynote remote control working from tethered iPhone?

Tags: keynote, remote-control

I’m failing to get Keynote on iPhone to work as the remote control for Keynote on iPad. It *will* work OK when they’re both on the same wireless network, but in the school I was trying to present in this morning, this wasn’t available to me.

So I connected (“tethered”) my iPad to my iPhone through its wifi connection, and turned on the ability for it to be remotely controlled. On the iPhone in Keynote under Manage Devices I could see and select the iPad. But when it came to actually trying to start the remote control, it consistently failed to find that same iPad.

Am I missing a trick?

Comment: I would imagine that it's because tethering doesn't truly expose each device to the other in the same way - it's just a 'pass-through', but idk if there's any workaround, so just a comment not an answer.